# Generating pandas dataframe with for loops

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

I want to do something that would look like this :
(list_team is a pandas DataFrame)

```
    count = 0
    for value_list in [list_team[count]]:
        home+str(count) = saison2018[saison2018.HomeTeam.isin(value_list)]
        away+str(count) = saison2018[saison2018.AwayTeam.isin(value_list)]
        count +=1
```

Of course this doesn't work,

EDIT :
What I'd like to have by doing this loop is this:

```
value_list = [list_team[0]]:
            home0 = saison2018[saison2018.HomeTeam.isin(value_list)]
            away0 = saison2018[saison2018.AwayTeam.isin(value_list)]
value_list = [list_team[1]]:
            home1 = saison2018[saison2018.HomeTeam.isin(value_list)]
            away1 = saison2018[saison2018.AwayTeam.isin(value_list)]
```

etc

Create pandas dataframes where the names would be home0 & away0, then home1 & away 1, then home2 & away1, etc... until the end of the list_team list.
Hope it's clear now.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but it seems like you want to group your `saison2018` DataFrame by `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam`? Have you looked at using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)?

Comment: You should probably store the results in a dictionary indexed by count, but the question becomes what you want to do with `home0`, `home1`, etc? I fear this may be a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 0):

i think one of them will work:

```
count = 0
for value_list in [list_team[count]]:
    exec("home%s= saison2018[saison2018.HomeTeam.isin(value_list)]" %(count))
    exec("away%s= saison2018[saison2018.AwayTeam.isin(value_list)]" %(count))
    count +=1

count = 0
for value_list in [list_team[count]]:
    exec("home%s= saison2018[saison2018.HomeTeam.isin(value_list)]" %(str(count)))
    exec("away%s= saison2018[saison2018.AwayTeam.isin(value_list)]" %(str(count)))
    count +=1
```